# Leaflet draw: prevent drawing through a custom overlay

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw

I have a leaflet draw implementation (in Angular) with a custom sidebar that overlaps the Map. It should not be possible to draw through that sidebar.
For circlemarkers I could solve this problem easily by using

```
pointer-events: all;
```

and

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

for the clickevents. That way any clicks will not arrive on the map, so no circlemarker is drawn.

My problem: this solution does not work when drawing eg. rectangles. Even with the code above, any click on the sidebar starts drawing a new rectangle or finishes the drawing of a rectangle.

How can I prevent the Map from registering these events on top of the sidebar. Why does it work for circlemarkers an not for polygons?

Comment: Most probably the problem is in z-order of html elements. Try setting z-index of your sidebar to some very high value, then catch mouse events in your sidebar and prevent event bubbling.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, z-index values seem to be correct. I catch the click / mousedown events and stop propagation. But that doesn't help ,  the polyon / rectangle / circle still start/stop drawing.

Comment: In this case debugging is the only solution. Going step by step through code and see what is happening.