# Prevent user from drawing a feature with Leaflet.draw

Tags: leaflet, javascript, leaflet-draw

In my application using Leaflet.draw the user can set point markers on a map.

I would like to allow the setting only in a certain area.

The function `isMarkerInsidePolygon(marker, polygon)` returns true, if the marker is inside the polygone, false if outside.

For this purpose, I think I have to check after `draw:drawstart`, but before `draw:created`, if `isMarkerInsidePolygon(marker, polygon)` returns true or false.

If it returns false, I want to prevent setting the marker, but still keep the drawing mode active. Is there a posibility to prevent the setting of a marker in leaflet.draw?

There is a similar question asked by Ben, but no exactly the same case:

 [Leaflet draw: prevent drawing through a custom overlay](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/320680/leaflet-draw-prevent-drawing-through-a-custom-overlay)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there seems to be no official hook to implement this, one has to resort to hack.

`L.Draw.Marker` class has internal `_onClick` method which is called when user clicks with mouse to create marker. This method can be replace with our own hacked method by modifying `L.Draw.Marker` class. We can check here if clicked point is within polygon and allow creation of marker or return immediately without creating it.

```
L.Draw.Marker.include({
  _onClick: function () {
    // our hack
    if (! isMarkerInsidePolygon(this._marker, polygon)) return;
    // original code
    this._fireCreatedEvent();
    this.disable();
    if (this.options.repeatMode) {
      this.enable();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. That sounds plausible for me. I will give it a try and let you know if it works next week.

Comment: Since no new class is created, just existing one modified, I replaced `extend` method with more appropriate `include` method (see https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-1-classes.html).

Comment: @pascatl So did you try it?

Comment: I gave it a short try, but actually I don't know how to make my polygon accessible for the function isMarkerInsidePolygon(this._marker, polygon) inside the L.Draw.Marker class :/

Comment: It's hard to give advice without seeing/knowing logic of your code. First answer woud be to define function at top level so it's accessible everywhere.

Comment: I managed to fix it. Your solution works. Thank you :)